# Cannot import name 'graycomatrix' from 'skimage.feature'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

I have successfully installed skimage packages but when I try to import the

```py
from skimage.feature import graycomatrix, graycoprops
```

it results in an error saying:

```py
cannot import name 'graycomatrix' from 'skimage.feature' (/Users/ain/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/feature/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 8):

Its name is greycomatrix. Syntax is

```py
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
```

Comment: Why is this misspelt in the official tutorial? :D https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_glcm.html

Answer (score 5):

To be more precise, to answer @smcs's comment and to update the accepted answer, **from version 0.19** as seen in this [pull request](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/5385) the functions are named `graycomatrix` and `graycoprops` and the documentation ([github](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/texture.py#L15-L156) and [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.graycomatrix)) and the tutorial are correct.

To sum up. For `skimage` version 0.19 and above, this is the right import and version:

```py
from skimage.feature import graycomatrix, graycoprops
```

and for older versions (but also till version 1.0 as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/6390)) holds @Prasanth's answer:

```py
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
```